# what does "AMA" mean in IOTA?

Tags: iota-network

Can someone explain what does "AMA" mean in IOTA? And it is abbreviated of what words? Is it related to sending message in IOTA ? or something else ?

Comment: This is an off-topic question.

Comment: @Zass Maybe you're right, but I thought it's a technical term in IOTA. if you want you can delete it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask me anything.
I need to type at least 30 characters for this answer to be accepted.

Comment: This term was coined on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AMA/), where there are many AMAs for different topics. [when you add this to your answer, you are above the 30 char limit without "cheating"]